# Solana SPL token rent

Tags: spl-token, fees

I want to create a Solana SPL token by "spl-token create-token" CLI command, then a token account by using "spl-token create-account" .
How to transfer SOL to this token account to get it rent exempted?

Answer (score 3):

Those commands should make the account rent-exempt by default.